# In decorator pattern how do you make sure the lowest level element is not a decorator?

Tags: design-patterns, decorator

In Decorator pattern you are supposed to wrap decorators around one central ConcreteComponent. But as far as I can see from looking at the class diagram ([from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern)) is that nothing is stopping me from using a ConcreteDecorator as the central element. And this is obviously not great, because its implementation of `operation()` most probably contains `component.operation()`. Do I miss something here? Is there a guard that I do not see that makes sure that the central element that is being decorated is a ConcreteComponent?

[image: decorator pattern class diagram]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably several ways, but I'd expect to have the `Decorator` to have code like this

```
abstract class Decorator implements Component {
    protected final Component decorated;
    protected Decorator(Component comp) {
        if (comp == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("must have decoration target");
        }
        decorated = comp;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if eg. the `Decorator` is an `interface`, you can just argue that having a valid decoratee is a precondition for `operation()` to work.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need such a check. Moreover - not only don't you need it, you really shouldn't have one. Having one will break down the abstraction.

Instead, you can have simpler restrictions - a decorator can't be created without something to decorate. I.e., it has no no-arg constructor, and you somehow check the component its decorating isn't null. That way, a decorator must decorate something, be it a concrete component or another decorator. That decorator, in turn, must also decorate something, and so on, until you reach a component that can be created out of thin air, with no other component necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your ConcreteDecorator as your central element. The idea is not to restrict you from using that, but to give you the flexibility to have multiple decorators and your client can treat them uniformly.

Basically **the type of your variable has to be the Decorator (the abstraction)** and your run time dependency can be whatever subclass of that abstraction you like. The concept is to decouple the implementation detail from the abstraction. So you can attach different decorators at run time and change behavior or add a state. The power of using the abstraction and not the concretion is that **you can change the concretion at run time as long as your type of the variable is the Decorator (the abstraction)**